# Is it possible to skip validation column names in dbunit

Tags: java, testing, junit, tdd, dbunit

Is it possible to skip validation of columns in DBUnit?

I prefer to use `FlatXmlDataSet` because it is easier to maintain. But for comparing the result I have to use `XmlDataSet` which has always all columns behind the table tag.

The `Assertion` method `assertEqualsIgnoreCols` might be a solution because it allows me to specify columns to ignore but there are to many columns and I do not want to add them all manually. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Ignoring some columns in comparison](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html#compareignorecolumns), you can also take a look at [How to exclude some table columns at runtime?](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#columnfilter)

Comment: First Link provided the solution. A little bit anoying that I have to loop through all tables on my own but thats better than duplicating the column definition. Thank you

Comment: All links are dead